# Asking for Name and Displaying input

Tags: c

I relatively new to the C language and StackOverflow. I'm trying to write a simple C code that will prompt user for their name and then display it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char name;

 printf("Let's do this, please enter your name:");
 scanf("%s", &name);
 printf("Your name is %s", name);

 return 0;
}
```

The code complies but after inputting the name, it displays Segmentation fault (core dumped).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need a null terminator as well as some characters to record a name, but you can't fit all those in a single `char`.  You need an array: `char name[32];` or similar (and should use `%31s` in the format to avoid overflows).  Also, with an array, you'll use just `name` (and not `&name`) in the call to `scanf()`.  And you should check that `scanf()` succeeded: `if (scanf("%31s", name) == 1) printf("Your name is %s\n");` — adding a newline too.

Comment: regarding: `char name;`  this only allows the name to be a max of 1 character long.  Suggest something similar to: `char name[ 100 ];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very small mistake @Jackie_Legs. In the declaration of the variable `name`, You have declared it as a `char`. so it holds just one character.

The solution: choose an arbitrary size for your name, say 10 or 15 characters. and declare it as an array of the size.

```
char name[15];
```

No changes in any other part of the program. Also, you should omit the `&` symbol in the `scanf` for strings.

So just one change and your code should work.

Here is the updated code which would work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char name[15];

  printf("Let's do this, please enter your name:");
  scanf("%s", name);
  printf("Your name is %s\n", name);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is mandatory to omit the `&` — if you include it, you pass a `char (*)[15]` to a function that is expecting a `char *`.  The types are quite different, though the values of the pointers happen to be the same.  A good compiler will warn you about the type mismatch.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jonathan. Just knew that it works even with the ampersand. Thanks for letting me know about this.

Answer (score 1):

It is because your name variable can only store single character and you are trying to store more than one character which will lead to unpredictable behaviour of program (e.g. segmentation fault).

If you know max length of name, declare variable name as array of character such as

```
char name[20];
```

Here you can store name with max length of 19 character. You can decide length of array as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare a string as because a single letter is stored in char and multiple characters along with a null character at the end forms an String which can be anything like names, etc.

In your code you have taken char which stores only a single character but in order to store your name (which is a string) you will have to take char array along with the size of the array.

Replace `char` **with** `char[size]` where size is the size for the string that you need.

Here are the changes I made to your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void)
{
  char name[30];

 printf("Let's do this, please enter your name:");
 scanf("%s", name);
 printf("Your name is %s", name);

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to omit the & from before name in the call to scanf(). For details, see another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287331/asking-for-name-and-displaying-input#comment91522520_52287375) of mine.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for this info I thought that in both ways they mean the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing error because of `char name;` **char** data type in C contain 1 character only in a variable. But your input is a string. 
You need to change the declaration of the variable from char to char array.

```
char name[50];
 printf("Let's do this, please enter your name:");
 scanf("%s", name);
 printf("Your name is %s", name);
```

Comment: You need to omit the `&` from before `name` in the call to `scanf()`.  For details, see another [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52287331/asking-for-name-and-displaying-input#comment91522520_52287375) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

`name` is declared as `char`, which means it can contain only one character. It is not sufficient to contain a string of characters (which a name usually consists of). You need to declare a `char` array (an array of characters).

The size of the array should be at least 1 more than the largest name you want to read in.
The extra byte is to contain the null terminating character `'\0'`.

```
char name[SizeOfLargestName + 1];
```

And when you use `scanf`, you need not use `&` because now name points to the first byte of the array.

```
 scanf("%s", name);
```